# Book Recommendations: GRE Subject Test In Biochemistry, Cell And Molecular Biology

Tags: genetics, biochemistry, molecular-biology, cell-biology, book-recommendation

There are probably a lot of really good answers that may vary significantly in terms of content.  I'm looking for a set of books that I can read in preparation for the [GRE Subject Test In Biochemistry, Cell And Molecular Biology](https://www.ets.org/gre/subject/about/content/biochemistry).  I have a Bachelors of Science degree, but never really studied any of the material on this exam (it's in a field which is not really related).  I'm interested in applying for a doctoral program in Biology, and would like to add something to my application so that it doesn't appear to come out of "left-field", as they say.  When I look at the questions from the sample exam in the link above, I can't tell whether they are introductory in scope or would require advanced study in particular areas.  Could somebody recommend a set of textbooks that would cover all of the ground for this test?  If one textbook exists which is sufficient, that would be wonderful, but I'm guessing that multiple texts will be required.  My goal is to learn the material necessary to do well on the exam as thoroughly as possible.

As an aside, I tried looking for study materials in online bookstores, but wasn't able to find anything that consistently got good reviews.  I don't think Princeton Review or Barron's have books on this subject, unless I overlooked something.  At any rate, I'm okay reading through a set of undergraduate university textbooks, but I really have no idea which ones would be good.

Comment: We're you able to find an appropriate book or selection of books? How did everything turn out? I am in the same situation and would like to know what books I should look for and the best way to study for the subject exam.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try [Lehninger Principles of Biochemistry](http://bcs.whfreeman.com/lehninger5e/default.asp?s=&n=&i=&v=&o=&rau=0). It covers all the topic except the part about cell motility and possibly, the 1-A-g ( I'm not too sure about it), but the book is for pretty advanced levels. I would not recommend it as a last minute reference book, but for thorough study it's great. Of course it's my personal opinion, so before you consider any book, I would rather advice you download a pdf copy of the same, to get a first hand experience.

Answer (score 1):

[Stryer's Biochemistry](http://www.macmillanhighered.com/catalog/static/whf/stryer4/) is a great book that pretty much covers all the requirements except those in A1 - Those are basic chemistry concepts which are not covered in Stryer. Any basic chemistry book will cover that. Make sure to verify, one-by-one, that all the test subjects are covered in Stryer. This answer is just a recommendation for a great Biochemistry book, not a guarantee for a one-shot success on the test.

Answer (score 1):

For metabolism, I definitely recommend *[Biochemical Pathways: An Atlas of Biochemistry](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Biochemical+Pathways%3A+An+Atlas+of+Biochemistry+and+Molecular+Biology%2C+2nd+Edition-p-9780470146842)* by Michal and Schomburg (eds). It is very extensive however, so memorizing its compounds and pathways takes much time and dedication. Generally, it works better as a reference book.